# systemctl enable libvirtd failed: too many levels of symbolic links on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, systemd, symbolic-link

I just installed `virt-manager` with APT (via `$ sudo apt-get install -y virt-manager`) and ran:

```
$ sudo gpasswd -a fusion809 libvirtd
```

(where fusion809 is the name of the user account I am presently signed in as) and that operation ran fine but then I ran:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
```

and it returned:

```
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Any ideas what the problem is and what its solution may be?

Comment: You could try `sudo systemctl enable /path/to/libvirtd.service` instead.